# Problem with linking ID of a task in DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I am working on to do app, and I cannot solve this problem.
The problem is linking the tasks with ID or PK...

i am getting this error:

**NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'update_task' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_task/**

and it is pointing that error is here (in template):

`<a href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Update</a>`

views.py

```
def updateTask(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)

    form =TaskForm(instance=task)

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'tasks/update_task.html',context)
```

template

```
<h3>To Do</h3>

<form  action='/' method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.title}}
  <input type="submit" name="Create Task">
</form>

{% for task in tasks %}

  <div class="">
    <a href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Update</a>
    <p>{{task}}</p>

  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import path
from tasks import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index, name='list'),
     path('update_task/<str:pk/', views.updateTask, name='update_task'),
 ]
```

Comment: You forgot to close the part in the `<str:pk>` block.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem tnx so much.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
path('update_task/<str:pk>/',views.updateTask, name='update_task'),
```